# OSRS Fishing Calculator "if...elif" block repeats results per item in list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, input, range

Creating a Fishing calculator where it can
**Be able to type in how many fish caught, which fish was caught, and show
the graph of XP gained with the total amount of fish in related to each 
fish.

First, graph the fish.
Second, determine which fish was caught then how many were caught.
Third, calculate total XP.

Print the plot/graph.**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:    
        fish_menu()
        types_of_fish = int(input('How many kinds of fish did you catch?: '))
        fishes = []
        caught = []
        if types_of_fish < 6:
            for i in range(1, types_of_fish+1): 
                which_fish = input('What was fish number {0}: '.format(i))
                catch = int(input('How many did you catch of {0}: '.format(which_fish)))
            #Adding the fish type and total amount into the empty lists
                fishes.append(which_fish)
                caught.append(catch)
                print()
            #We are able to at least have the first fish entry be calculated
            for i in range(types_of_fish):
                for f in fishes:
                    fish_calc()
                    print()
```

The result I keep getting most of the time is that it will repeat the top "if" statement for both numbers inputted for

```
catch = int(input('How many did you catch of {0}: '.format(which_fish)))
```

For example, if I catch 2 types of fish, the first being "Tuna" at 12 pieces and the second "Lobster" at 14 pieces this is what I receive:

```
How many kinds of fish did you catch?: 2
What was fish number 1: Tuna
How many did you catch of Tuna: 12

What was fish number 2: Lobster
How many did you catch of Lobster: 14

Catching 12 Tuna is 1200 total fishing XP

Catching 12 Tuna is 1200 total fishing XP

Catching 14 Tuna is 1400 total fishing XP

Catching 14 Tuna is 1400 total fishing XP
```

I don't know if I should change the function I created; fish_calc().

```
def fish_calc():
    if 'Tuna' in fishes:
        print('Catching {0} Tuna is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*100)) 
    elif 'Lobster' in fishes:
        print('Catching {0} Lobster is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*120)) 
    elif 'Swordfish' in fishes:
        print('Catching {0} Swordfish is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*140)) 
    elif 'Monkfish' in fishes:  
        print('Catching {0} Monkfish is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*150)) 
    elif 'Shark' in fishes:
        print('Catching {0} Shark is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*210))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues here:

1. You're printing twice, which is why it's double printing

```
Catching 12 Tuna is 1200 total fishing XP
```

2. There's a problem with `fish_calc()`. It will always hit the first if statement, which refers to Tuna, as long as you're not changing the `fishes` array. Take your first example, where you inputted 12 Tunas and 14 Lobsters. In this case, `fishes` contains `["Tuna", "Lobster"]`. The array is not being changed, so that's why when you execute `fish_calc()` twice, `fishes` is `["Tuna", "Lobster"]` every time it executes. Since it's checking if `fishes` contains "Tuna", which it does, it ignores the rest of the else if statements because the first if statement was satisfied.
3. The plural form of fish is not fishes :P

Comment: So once ```fish_calc()``` is executed, I need to have the ```fishes``` array remove the first of every list then have it re run?

So that once the ```for loop``` runs ```for i in range(types_of_fish)``` it just removes the first fish. 

P.S. I am sorry LOL I kept rewriting the list names because it wouldn't execute properly and once I had made it to the next step of the program I kept it as is as to not lose any work.

Comment: I wouldn't say you should remove the first of every list, you probably should remove whatever fish got you a hit in your cases. What if the list was `["Lobster", "Tuna"]`? Then it'd just remove Lobster after going to your first if statement about Tuna.

Comment: It worked once I added ```while len(fishes) > 0:``` at the beginning of ```fish_calc()```and ```fishes.pop(0)``` and ```caught.pop(0)```. I think I would have to make a new list and append to it if I wanna do the next step of the program. Thanks I appreciate the help!